# Why my form state is not correctly updated without using detectChange BEFORE modifying the form?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to make an Angular component using OnPush. When I use detectChange AFTER enabling or disabling some fields of my form, the form is not updated correctly. But if I use detectChange BEFORE then my form is correctly updated.

Can anyone explain me why do I need to use the detectChange before my form modification and not after ?

Big thx to you all !

```
import {
    AfterViewInit,
    ChangeDetectionStrategy,
    ChangeDetectorRef,
    Component,
    EventEmitter,
    forwardRef,
    Inject,
    Input,
    OnDestroy,
    OnInit,
    Output
} from '@angular/core';
import {ControlValueAccessor, FormArray, FormBuilder, FormGroup, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {M3ValidatorService} from '@macq/m3/libs/core';
import {L10N_LOCALE, L10nLocale, L10nTranslationService} from 'angular-l10n';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';
import {AuthMethod} from '../../../../constants/authentification-method';

@Component({
    selector: 'm3-parameters-external-server-form',
    templateUrl: './parametersServerFormComponent.html',
    styleUrls: ['../external-server-form.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => ParametersServerFormComponent),
            multi: true,
        },
    ],
})
export class ParametersServerFormComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, ControlValueAccessor {
    @Input() isCreation = false;
    @Input() isReadOnly = false;
    @Input() isSummary = false;
    @Input() protocol: string;

    @Output() editClicked: EventEmitter<never> = new EventEmitter<never>();
    @Output() validityChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

    form: FormGroup;
    defaultValue: any;
    disabled = false;
    sftpAuthMethod: string[];
    fieldsByProtocol: { [key: string]: string[] };
    activeFields: string[];
    authMethod: string;
    subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function
    onTouch: Function = (): void => {};
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function
    onChange: Function = (): void => {};

    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        @Inject(L10N_LOCALE) public locale: L10nLocale,
        private translation: L10nTranslationService,
        private validators: M3ValidatorService,
        private cd: ChangeDetectorRef
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.generateForm();
        this.initializeData();
        this.enableRightField();
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.subscriptions.forEach((item) => item.unsubscribe());
    }

    generateForm(): void {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
            host: [null, [this.validators.ipAddress({ hostname: false }), Validators.required]],
            privateKey: [null, Validators.required],
            port: [null, Validators.required],
            uri: null,
            user: null,
            password: [null, Validators.required],
            authMethod: [null, Validators.required],
            apiKey: null,
            subject: null,
            nisCode: null,
            privateKeyName: null,
            mails: null,
            passPhrase: null,
            headers: this.fb.array([this.fb.group({ option: null, value: null })]),
            proxy: this.fb.group({
                enabled: null,
                host: null,
                port: null,
                username: null,
                password: null,
            }),
        });

        this.subscriptions.push(
            this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((item: any) => {
                this.onChange(item);
                this.validityChange.emit(this.form.valid);
            })
        );

        this.form.controls.authMethod.valueChanges.subscribe((item: string) => {
            if (item === 'password' && this.authMethod !== item) {
                this.authMethod = item;
                const toRemove = ['privateKey', 'privateKeyName', 'passPhrase'];
                this.activeFields = this.activeFields.filter((field) => !toRemove.includes(field));
                this.activeFields.push('password');
                this.enableRightField();
            }
            if (item === 'private key' && this.authMethod !== item) {
                this.authMethod = item;
                this.activeFields = this.activeFields.filter((field) => field !== 'password');
                this.activeFields.push('privateKey', 'privateKeyName', 'passPhrase');
                this.enableRightField();
            }
        });

        this.setDefaultPortValue(this.protocol);
        this.defaultValue = this.form.getRawValue();
    }

    get headers(): FormArray<FormGroup> {
        return this.form.controls.headers as FormArray<FormGroup>;
    }

    addHeader(): void {
        this.headers.push(this.fb.group({ option: null, value: null }));
    }

    removeHeader(index: number): void {
        this.headers.removeAt(index);
    }

    initializeData(): void {
        this.sftpAuthMethod = Object.values(AuthMethod);
        this.fieldsByProtocol = {
            http: ['uri', 'user', 'password', 'headers', 'proxy'],
            ftp: ['host', 'port', 'user'],
            ftps: ['host', 'port', 'user', 'password'],
            sftp: ['host', 'port', 'user', 'authMethod'],
            ssh: ['host', 'port', 'user', 'authMethod'],
            smtp: ['mails', 'subject'],
            cevi: ['host', 'nisCode', 'apiKey'],
        };
        this.activeFields = this.fieldsByProtocol[this.protocol.toLowerCase()];
    }

    private enableRightField(): void {
        this.cd.detectChanges(); // This one make it works
        for (const key in this.form.controls) {
            if (this.activeFields.includes(key)) {
                this.form.controls[key].enable();
            }
            else {
                if (key === 'authMethod') {
                    this.form.controls.authMethod.disable();
                    console.log('auth')
                }
                else {

                    this.form.controls[key].disable();
                }
            }
            this.form.controls[key].updateValueAndValidity();
            this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
        }
        if (this.protocol === 'SSH' || this.protocol === 'SFTP' || this.protocol === 'FTPS') {
            this.form.controls.user.setValidators(Validators.required);
            this.form.controls.password.setValidators(Validators.required);
        } else {
            this.form.controls.user.clearValidators();
            this.form.controls.password.clearValidators();
        }
        this.form.controls.user.updateValueAndValidity();
        this.form.controls.password.updateValueAndValidity();
        this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
        this.cd.detectChanges(); // this one alone doesn't work
        console.log(this.form)
        for (const key in this.form.controls) {
            console.log(this.form.controls[key].status)
        }
    }

    private setDefaultPortValue(protocol: string) {
        let defaultValue: number;
        switch (protocol) {
            case 'SSH':
            case 'SFTP':
                defaultValue = 22;
                break;
            case 'FTPS':
                defaultValue = 990;
                break;
            case 'FTP':
                defaultValue = 21;
                break;
            default:
                defaultValue = 21;
                break;
        }
        this.form.controls['port'].setValue(defaultValue);
    }

    isFieldActive(controlName: string): boolean {
        return this.activeFields.includes(controlName);
    }

    onEditClick(): void {
        this.editClicked.emit();
    }

    registerOnChange(onChange: Function): void {
        this.onChange = onChange;
    }

    registerOnTouched(onTouch: Function): void {
        this.onTouch = onTouch;
    }

    writeValue(value: any): void {
        if (!value) value = this.defaultValue;
        for (const key in value) {
            this.form.controls[key].setValue(value[key]);
        }
    }

    setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
        this.disabled = isDisabled;
    }
}
```

I expect that calling detectChange after my function enableRightField() changes correctly my form.

Comment: My first line is not show but it was: 'Hi everyone' :D

Comment: please create a online stackblitz or simiar system, reproducing your error on that, and share link so people can debug, and help better